# Function that takes longest number from String in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes the longest number from a String in Haskell.

Example: "Test12 Test123 Test1234"

This should return 1234 because 1234 is the longest number in this String.

This is how my code currently looks like:

```
import Data.Char

longNumber :: String -> Int
longNumber n = length (filter ((> 1) . length . filter isDigit) . words) n
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: What are the valid test cases(all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want something like:

```
longNumber :: String -> Int
longNumber = read . maximumBy (comparing length) . map (filter isDigit) . words
```

Comment: Do you tried for the "Test123Test1234", "Test" and "" test cases?

Comment: @StevenDobay - This answer is based on the OPs code, so yes there are a lot of cases it will break down on.

Comment: Isn't the longest number also the largest number? How about something like : `longnumber = maximum . map (read . filter isDigit) . words `?

Comment: @ssm - Not necessarily if the number has leading zeros.

Comment: @Lee Oh ok. Hadn't seen that one!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'takeWhile' function with 'isDigit' and recursion.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Function

getLongest [] = []
getLongest l = getMax $ getNumbers l []
 where getNumbers [] ls = ls
   getNumbers l@(x:xs) ls 
    | isDigit x = getNumbers (dropWhile isDigit l) (ls ++ [takeWhile isDigit l])
    | otherwise = getNumbers xs ls
   getMax ls = if (ls == []) then [] else (maximumBy (compare `on` length) ls)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.Char
import Data.Function
import Data.List

takeAllNumbers :: String → [String]
takeAllNumbers "" = []
takeAllNumbers s = let (n,s') = takeNumber s
                   in n:takeAllNumbers s'
  where takeNumber = span isDigit ∘ dropWhile (not ∘ isDigit)

maxNumber :: String → Maybe Int
maxNumber "" = Nothing
maxNumber s = let allNums = takeAllNumbers s
              in if null allNums
                  then Nothing
                  else Just $ read $ maximumBy (compare `on` length) allNums
```

The function `takeAllNumbers` extracts all the numbers in the given String while `maxNumber` selects the number with the max length in its String form. Note that `maxNumber` returns `Maybe Int` because it is possible that in the String there are no numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an assumption that numbers are always in separate words. What if your string had no spaces? The `words` function would not help you, and simply getting rid of of non digit characters could cause you issues. For example `"ab1c2d3 test12"` would become `["123", "12"].

Also, you will need to return a Maybe Int (what if there were no numbers?)

Below is my first attempt at the problem.

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)                                                 
import Data.Char (isDigit)                                                  
import Data.List (maximumBy, null, groupBy)                                 

longestNumber :: String -> Maybe Int                                        
longestNumber s                                                             
            | null nums = Nothing                                           
            | otherwise = Just $ read $ maximumBy (comparing length) nums   
     where                                                                  
        nums = filter (isDigit . head) groups                               
        groups = groupBy (\a b -> isDigit a == isDigit b) s
```